# GeoServer and SLD : How to get rid of the newline after using numberFormat

Tags: geoserver, sld

Using GeoServer and SLD I am trying to use number format and concatenation but I am getting a newline generated after the number format:

```
<TextSymbolizer>
  <Label>
    <ogc:Function name="numberFormat">
      <ogc:Literal>###,###,###</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:PropertyName>AREASQFT</ogc:PropertyName>
    </ogc:Function>
    <ogc:Literal>sq.ft.</ogc:Literal>
...
```

Displays:

```
8,735
sq. ft.
```

I would like the label to display such as:

```
8,735 sq. ft.
```

I tried using the Concatenate fuction:

```
<TextSymbolizer>
  <Label>
    <ogc:Function name="Concatenate">
      <ogc:Function name="numberFormat">
        <ogc:Literal>###,###,###</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:PropertyName>AREASQFT</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Function>
      <ogc:Literal>sq.ft.</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
...
```

But I am still getting a newline:

```
8,735
sq. ft.
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your first styling with the poly_landmarks example in GeoServer using the LAND property for your label and number formatting.
I get the desired behavior on my development version. Perhaps you can test with a newer version of GeoServer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it with `<VendorOption name="autoWrap">50</VendorOption>` in the style sheet. See also http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html